# different app on the same machine cannot always been built for android

Tags: android, build, configuration, project, ionic4

I have different app project based on Ionic 4 on my pc but often it happens that when I finished developing one and do the android build, then, the other one cannot be built anymore. 
Is this happening to you as well?
How do you suggest me to do?
Thank you very much in advance,
Chris

Comment: Can you post what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, could you please provide more information about your question ? Logs, Errors, screenshots, etc. so others can help you better?